# How to bring back the tools menu under editor type?

Tags: tools

so this might be a stupid question but as I am a complete beginner I will need some help with this - I have no idea how to bring back the toolbar under the Editor type - I am not even sure of the correct name for it so I am attaching a screenshot.
I am using Blender 3.0 on mac

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you should ever encounter this problem again, if I understand the question correctly you were looking for these "tools":

[image: properties tabs]

These are the *Properties Tabs*, they belong to the *Properties Editor*. In your screenshot it shows you have switched both editor windows in the right column to the *Outliner*. To get the *Properties* back, click on the dropdown menu in the top left corner of the editor window you want to change. There you choose *Properties*.

[image: properties editor]